# MS SQL Server Dynamic Port Range

Tags: sql-server, port, dynamic

I understand that a SQL server named instance will default to dynamic ports, and I know HOW to [change that to a static IP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/how-to-change-the-dynamic-port-of-the-sql-server-named-instance-to-an-static-port-in-a-sql-server-2005-cluster):

BUT, I'm still wondering what that dynamic range will be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a range as such. It uses 1433 by default.

If you're referring to the dynamic port range for TCP/UDP, it is 49152–65535. Refer to [wikipedia's list of TCP/UDP ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports:_49152.E2.80.9365535) for more info. I don't know if this is of any relevance to your question though.

Also this is the default range.

To know the exact range you can use the following command on the server

`NetSh INT IPV4 SHOW DynamicPort TCP`.

This range can be changed to default using the following command

`NetSh INT IPV4 SET DynamicPort TCP Start=49152 num=16384`.

Reference : [Default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista)

Comment: A single default instance will use 1433, but clustered or named instances use the sql browsing service to arbitrate the port number to clients, but I need to know what port range that could in order to open them on the internal firewall.

Comment: Quick Joe Smith is correct about the range, check out this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174904).